# how to show blog on a page without using iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I have website where I need to show a blog inside my website, so i tried doing that by using iframe.Now the problem is since the blog is bigger in size, my iframe shows scroll bars and I don't want that and also I would like to know if there is any other way to show the blog in my website like if I am able to show the website in div that will be cool since div size grows as data grows.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to use any server side programming (PHP, asp, asp.net, perl etc)?

Comment: What blogging site are you using? There may be an API (blogger has this http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/) you can use to to retireve the blog data you want. You can then display this on your site however you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily load any web content into a div using [Prototype's AJAX updater](http://prototypejs.org/api/ajax/updater). To work around the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) you'll need a script on the server side, which loads the blog content for you, and "reflects" it back to the AJAX code, which is pretty straightforward to do using almost any server side solution (PHP, ASP, whatever).

Answer (score 1):

Can you get a feed of the content in any common standard format (RSS, Atom etc) that you can then display on your site in a style that matches your layout better?

Here's a [pretty good tutorial on building a simple RSS reader using jQuery](http://visualrinse.com/2008/09/24/how-to-build-a-simple-rss-reader-with-jquery/).